# Solving for voltage across resistor in mesh circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis

Hey all I am once again asking for help on circuit analysis,

[image]

Ive done mesh analysis and the results are
Ia = IR1 = 0.1641A,
Ib = IR4 = 7.33mA,
Ic = IR8 = -0.1089A,
Id = IR9 = -0.06373A,

now what i'm supposed to do next is find out the voltage across all the resistors, but Theres too many nodes so i'm unsure where to start, I know I can use ohm's law to find VR1 = 1.641V, VR4 = 0.2933v, VR8 = -8.717v and VR9 = -5.736v but the others I have no idea how to even start.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Write all the equations for all the loops you see and then go to wolphram alpha -> system equation solver and press solve.

Comment: Others have a sum of *two* of the currents flowing through them. Mind the directions.

Comment: ive already calculated the values of the mesh and now im trying to calculate for voltage across the resistors but i dont know where to start

Comment: Find the currents flowing through each resistor  and then use KVL to find the voltage.

Comment: Use the net current through the resistor as determined from your mesh results.

Comment: Ohms Law gives the voltages all around the outer square and you have a voltage source between node 8 and ground.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need KVL or a bunch of equations. The current through each resistor can be expressed as the sum or difference of 2 of your mesh currents. If the mesh currents have known values then you just need simple arithmetic to find the current through each resistor. After that, Ohm's Law is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

You've done the hard part already.  Looking at your diagram, you simply sum the currents algebraically. Pick a direction to be positive (and be consistent), and then add or subtract the other current accordingly. eg.
$$ Vr_6 = R6 * (Id - Ib)$$

[image]